# UTF8 Encoding problems when exporting posts

Tags: export, encoding

I have a Wordpress installation with MySQL encoded as utf8_general_ci. I'm trying to export it using wordpress' export tool, but the result XML breaks some special characters such as "é", "ê", etc turning them into "Ã©" for example.

The XML file is being downloaded into a Windows machine and scp'ed into a Linux. In both platforms the encode is off.

I checked the resulting xml with "file" and it´s telling me it is a UTF8 file.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Which program are you viewing the XML file in? Does the XML file report an encoding in its `<?xml ?>` header?

Comment: Good question! I'm looking at it with cat/vi/vim in Linux and also in Windows and that´s where I see it wrong. If I use Notepad++, for example, in Windows the characters are showed correctly. Also, it has the xml header with encoding set to UTF-8: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>. Looks like my problem is with Linux based editors?

Comment: The file is likely correct, but the program that you're viewing it in is probably interpreting it with ISO-8859-1 / latin1 encoding. The "Ã©" pairing is something I have often seen when viewing a UTF-8 encoded 'é' in latin1.

Comment: I added set encoding=utf-8 to my .vimrc and it made the trick. Thanks a lot! (@Bendoh if you answer the question I can mark it as yours)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file is likely correct, but the program that you're viewing it in is probably interpreting it with ISO-8859-1 / latin1 encoding.

The `Ã©` pairing is something I have often seen when viewing a UTF-8 encoded `é` in latin1.

Be sure that the program you are viewing the file in is set to view in UTF-8 encoding.